# rbl-списки для блокирования спама

Tags: email, спам

Использую на `postfix` `rbl`-списки от `zen.spamhaus.org` и `dnsbl.sorbs.net`.
Выбор на эти списки у меня пал, после того, как мне свой же `IP` пришлось из `DUHL` удалять из этих баз, причём в `spamhaus` более простая, продуманная и быстрая система удаления, нежели в `sorbs`.

Возникли вопросы, а нужны ли они мне оба этих списка?

Не сильно ли поиск по обоим замедляет получение/отправку почты и как это проверить в `postfix`?

Не используют ли они списки одних и тех же адресов, и если список выбрать 
одну из них, и если да то какую и почему?

Какие быстрее, какие надёжнее?

Может вы по личному опыту предложите ваши более быстрые и/или надёжные списки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sorbs` помечает сервера `Google`, как сервера рассылающие спам.
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/HruhcLvodkY
Проблема ещё с 2005-ого года, обсуждалась на форуме 3,5 года назад и судя по моим логам, есть и сейчас.
Так что категорически не рекомендую использовать любые `rbl`-списки от `sorbs.net`

Вполне достаточно использовать единственный общий `rbl`-список `zen.spamhaus.org`